# How to write a click event on MediaElement when pause button clicked?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement to play video. I want to call a c# function when clicking on the pause icon of video.

```
 <MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened"  Width="450" Height="250" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded"  />
```

How to write a click event in .cs file for this? Other than adding play and pause icons manually? I need `AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189079(v=vs.95).aspx) you can use event `CurrentStateChanged`. When state change to `Paused` user must use pause button if you don't change state from code.

In XAML:

```
<MediaElement CurrentStateChanged="Media_State_Changed" ... />
```

And in C#:

```
private void Media_State_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(media.CurrentState ==  MediaElementState.Paused)
    {
       //do some work
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote this code in Visual Studio 2017. It shows me error. Said:
'The Member "CurrentStateChanged" is not recognized or is not accessible.